# Is std::unique_ptr an application of RAII?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Is that an accurate description of it? Does it make sense?

Are you guaranteed that the object it points to won't be deleted until the unique_ptr goes out of scope [even if you're not using the unique_ptr]?

Comment: Wanna just make that the answer so I can give you a check?

Comment: yes, it's an RAII class. I don't see how "the object it points to won't be deleted until the unique_ptr goes out of scope" is relevant – a sufficiently stupid programmer can `delete ptr.get()` and corrupt memory at will, but this doesn't make `unique_ptr` "less RAII".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I was just curious if it is possible for the compiler to ever clean up the garbage before it actually goes out of scope if it's not being used. Does that make sense?

Comment: @wrhall no, it doesn't. The compiler knows nothing about the semantics of objects, it merely generates calls to constructors and destructors as necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `std::unique_ptr` follows the RAII design principle.

No, `std::unique_ptr` does not prevent other code from doing something stupid, like calling `delete` on a pointer that belongs to the `unique_ptr`.  The `unique_ptr` itself will call a deleter<sup>1</sup> on the object it owns when either:

1. it goes out of scope

or

2. the `unique_ptr` is reassigned (via `operator=` or `reset`) to point to a different object

One can also revoke `unique_ptr`'s ownership of an object by moving to a different smart pointer, or using the `release` member function.  This breaks the association between the object and the `unique_ptr` and `unique_ptr` will no longer clean up the object.

---

<sup>1</sup> The default deleter will use either `delete` or `delete []`, depending on whether the target has array type.  But `unique_ptr` is a template and its deleter can be customized, for example the cleanup operation for a `FILE*` can be chosen to be a call to `fclose`.

This capability can be used to schedule an arbitrary cleanup action to take place when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.  RAII is used for keeping locks, closing files, and so forth -- clearly there would be major problems if the cleanup action were performed early just because the compiler didn't see any future usage of the smart pointer.  Luckily the C++ object lifetime rules are completely deterministic (even the order of destruction for multiple automatic variables in the same scope is well defined), and you can count on the smart pointer cleaning up its owned object exactly when the smart pointer is itself destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr` is RAII, as the creation of the object also initializes it.

> Are you guaranteed that the object it points to won't be deleted until the unique_ptr goes out of scope [even if you're not using the unique_ptr]?

If you make a few assumptions:

- You don't move the unique_ptr (that would cause the newly moved to location to be the one that will delete
- You don't delete the pointer yourself or add it to another control structure.

Or put more succinctly, yes it will live that long.

Answer (score 2):

It is an application of RAII, indeed.

But you are not granted that the object it points to is not deleted by someone else before the unique_ptr goes out of scope.

E.g.

```
int* p = new int;
int* cp = p;
std::unique_ptr<int> up(p);
delete cp;
```

will give undefined behavior.

Comment: The `undefined behaviour' in this instance would be throwing a software developer into a crevasse.

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` can be used for RAII, but doesn't prevent you from doing something like this:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo{};

int main()
{
    Foo* pFoo = new Foo;

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> upFoo(pFoo);
    delete pFoo; // WRONG, double deletion when upFoo's destructor is called
}
```

Usually, the best way to use smart pointers is to pass the raw pointer as their constructor or make-like function, such as

```
#include <memory>

class Foo{};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> upFoo(new Foo); // or make_unique in C++14
}
```